# in the numpy function np.allclose(), what the parameters 'atol' and 'rtol' mean?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)

I understand the meaning of a tolerance in the sense of how close can the elemnts be for the function to return True, but can't figure out  what is the difference between absolute tolerance and relative tolerance.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ofcourse, it says this:   rtol:
The relative tolerance parameter (see Notes).

atol: 
The absolute tolerance parameter (see Notes).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica     the documentation doesnt explain what is the meaning of relative and absolute. i think absolute tolerance is the kind of tolerance i undestand, but i have no idea what relative tolerance mean. maybe its a language problem even though i understand the meaning of relative and tolerance

Comment: It says "see Notes". Did you do that? The role of `rtol` and `atol` is explained there.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica i saw that also, cant find there an exlanation. ill be very happy if someonee can explain it to me in simple english